# Matplotlib Subplots are jammed together

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have modeled mnist dataset and the test set (`x_test`) is of length 2000 digit images and the model predicts wrong on the images with indices `wrong_predicted_images` in test set. I am trying to plot the images along with the correct labels ( from test set: `y_test`). I came up with this. However, when I plot it, all the images are gets jammed together.

```
num_cols = 5
num_images = len(wrong_predicted_images)
num_rows = num_images//num_cols +1
f, axarr = plt.subplots(num_rows, num_cols, sharex='col', sharey='row')
f.subplots_adjust(hspace=1,wspace= 1) # to have space between images
for count, i in enumerate(wrong_predicted_images):
  x, y = count//num_cols, count % num_cols
  axarr[x,y].imshow(x_test[i])
  axarr[x,y].imshow(x_test[i])
  axarr[x,y].set_title(y_test[i], loc = 'right')
  plt.grid(False)
plt.show()
```

Here is the produced image

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: `num_rows = (num_images-1) // num_cols + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My GUESS is that you are trying to plot WAY TOO MANY images in a single figure, in the following I'll mimic your procedure using 9 vs 299 images, the second figure is suspiciously similar to what you've shown…

```
In [26]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    ...: import numpy as np 
    ...: img = np.arange(54*108).reshape(108,54)                                          

In [27]: N = 9 
    ...: nc = 5 
    ...: nr = (N-1)//nc + 1 
    ...: f, axarr = plt.subplots(nr, nc, sharex='col', sharey='row') 
    ...: f.subplots_adjust(hspace=1, wspace=1) 
    ...: for c in range(N): 
    ...:     x, y = c//nc, c%nc 
    ...:     axarr[x,y].imshow(img) 
    ...:     axarr[x,y].set_title('title')
```

[image]

```
In [28]: N = 299 
    ...: nc = 5 
    ...: nr = (N-1)//nc + 1 
    ...: f, axarr = plt.subplots(nr, nc, sharex='col', sharey='row') 
    ...: f.subplots_adjust(hspace=1, wspace=1) 
    ...: for c in range(N): 
    ...:     x, y = c//nc, c%nc 
    ...:     axarr[x,y].imshow(img) 
    ...:     axarr[x,y].set_title('title')
```

[image]

Comment: isn't it possible to paginate the large figure? If not, maybe I should loop every 10 images and create a figure and plot them.

Comment: As far as I can tell a figure is a figure,  if I'm right you have to decide how many images reasonably fit in a figure and loop on figures, rows and columns --- incidentally, I was extending my answer to include such a solution.  The tricky part is to delete the unused subplots in the last figure...

Comment: It's too tricky because it's easy to remove the last subplots but this leads to  another problem, the x axis ticks are not drawn ... probably for you is better to have blank subplots but the correct xticks below the figure.